# What is the correct way to send suggestions to the user with the [Suggestions] response type?

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

I have tried for what feels like hours to get the Composer to send a suggestion back to the user. I want the suggestion, if clicked, to open another website.

First, I created a template:

```
# urlCard(title, value)
[CardAction
    Type = openUrl
    Title = ${title}
    Value = ${value}
]
```

This works fine if I use it from a hero card, for example:

```
[HeroCard
      title = Click that button
      text = This is a test hero card
      buttons = ${urlCard( 'Google', 'https://google.com/' )}
    ]
```

But I cannot get suggestions to work with `[Suggestions`:

```
[Suggestions
      SuggestionActions = ${urlCard( 'Google', 'https://google.com/' )}
    ]
```

This is what I see in the Bot Framework Emulator:

[image]

How can I send suggestions to the user, without being in a hero card?

Comment: There is no structure called "Suggestions" in the Bot Framework. What happens if you try `Activity` instead of `Suggestions`?

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with the Composer but I can tell you how the Python API works and maybe it can help you to figure this out.
In Python (JS is very similar) you would do something like:

```
CardAction(title="Yes?", type=ActionTypes.im_back, value='yes')
CardAction(title="No?", type=ActionTypes.im_back, value='no')
```

The suggested actions disappear after the user makes a selection and the bot will receive a message with the action value. I don't think you can embed a URL however, so maybe this is the actual issue you have.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
[Activity
    SuggestedActions = ${openUrl( 'Google', 'https://google.com/' )}
]
```